# Buffer size too small. size = 131072 needed = 5569380 but I have hive conf set hive.exec.orc.default.buffer.size=5600000;

Tags: hive, amazon-emr

I am struggling to complete a hive query. My hive confs:

```
set hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode=nonstrict;
set hive.exec.dynamic.partition=true;
set hive.exec.max.dynamic.partitions=10000;
set mapreduce.map.memory.mb=10000;
set mapreduce.reduce.memory.mb=10000;
set mapreduce.reduce.memory.mb=10000;
set hive.exec.max.dynamic.partitions.pernode=10000;
set hive.execution.engine=tez;
set hive.exec.stagingdir=/tmp/hive/;
set hive.exec.scratchdir=/tmp/hive/;
set hive.groupby.orderby.position.alias=true;
set hive.vectorized.execution.enabled=true;
set hive.exec.parallel=true;
set hive.llap.io.enabled=false;
set hive.exec.orc.default.buffer.size=5600000;
```

After running the hive file with nohup, if I scroll through it after the query fails, I see several times the message:

> java.io.IOException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Buffer size too small. size = 131072 needed = 5569380

Then right at the end:

> killed/failed due to:OTHER_VERTEX_FAILURE]DAG did not succeed due to VERTEX_FAILURE. failedVertices:1 killedVertices:14

Not sure what other information to provide? It looks like my last hive conf isn't working since I set it after seeing this error output:

```
set hive.exec.orc.default.buffer.size=5600000;
```

Are there any confs I can add or edit to attempt this again?

Comment: Any progress about this